# Condicional IF dentro de consulta SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Tenho a seguinte consulta:

```
$string = "
SELECT DISTINCT(idClientes), nome FROM clientes WHERE idClientes IN ( 
 SELECT idClientes FROM planosclientes WHERE idPlanosClientes IN (
   SELECT distinct(idPlanoClientes) FROM pagamentos WHERE mesReferencia NOT IN ('".$mesReferencia."') 
    ) and DATEDIFF (CURDATE(), CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(),'%Y,%m' ),'-', diaVencimento)) > ".$dias."
    UNION
    SELECT idPlanosClientes FROM planosclientes WHERE idPlanosClientes NOT IN                                                (SELECT distinct(idPlanoClientes) FROM pagamentos)
           ) ORDER BY nome";
```

Acontece que se o campo `diaVencimento` for maior que o dia atual, em php `date('d')`, a expressão `$mesReferencia` que recebe um valor do tipo `date('Y-m')` precisa ser do mês anterior. Ou seja `date('Y-m')` menos 1 mês.

Como fazer essa condicional?

Tabelas em questão:

```
CREATE TABLE clientes (
  idClientes int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  tipoClientes char(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  nome varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  cpf char(11) DEFAULT '',
  cnpj char(14) DEFAULT '',
  email varchar(100) DEFAULT '',
  telefone varchar(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  celular varchar(11) DEFAULT '',
  bloqueado char(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (idClientes)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=14 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE pagamentos (
  idPagamentos int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  idPlanoClientes int(10) NOT NULL,
  idAdmins int(1) NOT NULL,
  mesReferencia char(7) NOT NULL,
  dataPgto date NOT NULL,
  valorPgto double NOT NULL,
  multa double NOT NULL,
  juros double NOT NULL,
  desconto double NOT NULL,
  totalPago double NOT NULL,
  formaPgto char(2) NOT NULL,
  observacao text,
  PRIMARY KEY (idPagamentos)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE planosclientes (
  idPlanosClientes int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  idClientes int(10) NOT NULL,
  idPlanos int(10) NOT NULL,
  valorCombinado double NOT NULL,
  diaVencimento varchar(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  dataInstalacao date NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
  observacao text,
  login varchar(25) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  senha varchar(25) DEFAULT '',
  bloqueado char(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (idPlanosClientes)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=8 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: Sua consulta ficaria muito melhor (e mais rápida) se utilizasse JOINS, mas para lhe ajudar precisaria ver a estrutura das tabelas em uso. Outra dica é utilizar as próprias funções do banco para fazer o cálculo da data ao invés de concatenaruma função PHP na sua consulta sql

Comment: Coloquei a estrutura das tabelas!

Comment: Elas não tem foreign keys? ou você não colocou ?

Comment: tem mas não coloquei. Informei isso na SQL $mesReferencia vem do formulário e $dias também pois são dias e atraso

Comment: Se ***CURDATE(),'%d' ) < diaVencimento***, a variavél ***$mesReferencia ***que recebe ***date('Y-m')*** do php seja decrescida em 1 mês e caso contrário, se mantém

Comment: Algumas dúvidas: 1 - O mês referência que você passa do PHP é sempre o mês atual (`date(Y-m)`) ou pode ser um valor informado? 2 - O objetivo dessa linha `DATEDIFF (CURDATE(), CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(),'%Y,%m' ),'-', diaVencimento))` é diminuir a data atual da data formada pelo concat com o `diaVencimento` para comparar com a `$dias` , se for o que deve acontecer se o curdate retornar um dia menor que a data da concatenação ? 3 - Você criou um union de idClientes com idPlanosClientes isso está correto? não faz sentido!

Comment: 4 - O union é para tirar todos os clientes que tem planos mas não tem pagamentos ?

Comment: 1) mesReferencia é o mês corrente. Caso o diaVencimento que é próprio de cada contratação de plano for após o dia da tiragem do relatório, então o mesReferencia para aquele lançamente precisa ser o anterior! 2) Saber quantos dias em atraso o cliente esta desde o dia do vencimento até a data da tiragem 3) As 2 clausulas unidas por Union pedem idPlanosClientes e estão dentro de um IN() 4) isso, clientes que tem plano mas não pagou nenhuma mês ainda!

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29728/discussion-between-jorge-campos-and-carlos-rocha).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Após as dúvidas tiradas nos comentários a consulta final para o que você precisa seria essa:

```
$string = "
  SELECT c.idClientes, c.nome
    FROM clientes c 
           INNER JOIN planosclientes PC ON (c.idClientes = pc.idClientes)
           INNER JOIN pagamentos p ON (pc.idPlanosClientes = p.idPlanoClientes)
   WHERE p.mesReferencia != (CASE WHEN pc.diaVencimento>EXTRACT(DAY from CURDATE()) 
                                  THEN DATE_FORMAT((CURDATE() - INTERVAL '1' MONTH), '%Y-%m')
                                  ELSE DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%Y-%m') 
                              END)
     AND DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT( CURDATE(), '%Y-%m' ), '-', pc.diaVencimento)) > ".$dias."
   ORDER BY c.nome ";
```

A condição que você procura é feita pelo comando `CASE`, no seu caso:

```
(CASE WHEN pc.diaVencimento>EXTRACT(DAY from CURDATE()) 
      THEN DATE_FORMAT((CURDATE() - INTERVAL '1' MONTH), '%Y-%m')
      ELSE DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%Y-%m') 
  END)
```

Veja que eu substitui a utilização do `date('Y-m')` pela função do banco `DATE_FORMAT( CURDATE(), '%Y-%m' )`

O `UNION` elimina os clientes que tem plano e não fizeram pagamentos, assim sendo a utilização do JOIN atende a este filtro.

Qualquer problema é só escrever aí nos comentários.

Comment: Estou pensando aqui. Se o diaVencimento é maior que a data da tiragem do relatório, logo, ver se o mês anterior do cara está pago seria bom haja visto que o relatório é só daquele mês? O que você acha?

Comment: Dado a estrutura de suas tabelas, pagamento (dataPgto date NOT NULL) , significa que um registro nessa tabela significa o próprio registro do pagamento, o que, novamente, o INNER JOIN já resolve. Quando o mês de referência é o anterior ele já está trazendo o registro que foi pago!

Comment: Muito obrigado!